# Do incoming https posts require https URL's

Tags: .htaccess, http

We would like to have HTTP posts from secure servers be secure on our end.

Do the posts need to be made to *https*://ourserver.com, or does it work to post to *http*://ourserver.com, and then redirect to https via htaccess?

It would be nice if the latter were true in some fashion, as we're looking at 100's of URL's that would need to be updated manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should post directly to an `https:` URL.

User agents [do not resubmit the POST request](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/99894/41651) if the response was a 301 or 302. And while the 307 status code can be used to indicate that the POST request should be resubmitted, most user agents do not support it.

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't even considered that aspect. If the user agent was able to resubmit the post, would the first post even have been secure?

Comment: No, clearly not.